# Is there a way in C#.Net to find the location of a textbox control on a Winform relative to the screen resolution?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know the location property gives you the location of the control relative to the Winform it is on.  But I want to know the x,y coordinates relative to the top left corner of the display, not the Winform.

I had suggestions for using com interop and make an unmanaged call but wanted to know if there was something native to .Net.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [the Control.PointToScreen method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Computes the location of the specified client point into screen coordinates.

The inverse is [the Control.PointToClient method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx), by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the following code to get me what I wanted.  controlScreenPoint is a System.Drawing.Point object. `controlScreenPoint = myTextbox.PointToScreen(new Point(myTextbox.Location.X, myTextbox.Location.Y));`

Comment: I got my code compiling but I have hit a snag. My screen resolution of my primary display is screenResolution.Height:900x1440 both by checking my OS settings but also viewing the values of `Rectangle screenResolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;` However, when i make my PointToScreen call, the controlScreenPoint that is set sometimes is a point that is outside 900x1440. But my top left of my winform is definitely in the main display area. This happens when I move my winform down and to the right of the main display.

Comment: I figured out my issue. The screen coordinates I was getting were offset by the winform my textbox control was in. For my purposes I need to call based on top most Form.  `controlScreenPoint = myTextbox.TopLevelControl.PointToScreen(myTextbox.Location);`

Comment: I found out you don't want to use TopLevelControl. It only worked for me because I had a simple tester app and the textbox was in the sole Winform. When I put this in my real app the coordinates were messed up. The right thing to do is use Parent instead of TopLevelControl.